# functions of random variables notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

I understand that a random variable $X$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. What I fail to understand is why people when defining a new random variable $Y$, based on some function $g$ that operates on the output of $X$, use the notation $Y=g(X)$. I have seen that both [in this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1596065/50256) and also on the MIT lectures on probability by Prof. Tsitsiklis ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3MOahpLxj6A) on 30:55 and onwards). I think this notation makes no sense at all. The domain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$, not some "set of functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$" (which is what the "set of random variables" is). In my view the correct notation ought to be:

$$ Y = g \circ X $$

where $\circ$ is function composition. Seen in this light $g \circ X$ is a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (hence, a legitimate random variable) and $g(x)$ (lowercase $x$) is a value in $\mathbb{R}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: A random variable $X$ is a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. If $g$ is a measurable function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, then $g(X)$ is a measurable function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$, and too is a random variable.

Comment: @Math1000 but $X$ is not in $\mathbb{R}$. So I don't see how can you write $g(X)$. I admit my foundations are not solid enough as I don't really know what "measurable" means. Is this the crux of the matter or is it tangential? Because if I remove the word "measurable" from your comment, then it makes no sense. $g(X)$ is not from $Ω$ to $\mathbb{R}$,  and I don't even know what it stands for. $g o X$ however, is indeed from $Ω$ to $\mathbb{R}$,  and that's exactly my point.

Comment: It is simply a (rather lazy) convention in probability to write $Y=g(X)$ instead of $Y(\omega) = g(X(\omega))$, much like $\mathbf{P}(X \in A)$ is a shorthand notation for $\mathbf{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A\})$. Formulas in this area would become quite messy without these conventions.

Comment: @SangchulLee Lazy or not, shorthand notation is definitely a boon. Imagine insisting that a graph theorist write e.g. $\{u,v\}$ for an edge instead of $uv$.

Comment: @Math1000, I definitely agree. Hiding unnecessary details is so useful in practice. :)